# Zune HD networking

Tags: c#, xna, zune-hd

Is there a way to access internet from Zune HD (from XNA app or maybe another app)? I've found nothing in official documentation, but maybe there is a hack?

For example, Twitter and Weather programs work fine with the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networking on Zune can only be used to access the **Xbox Live service** and this allows you to download GamerTag data and communicate between other XNA based games for multiplayer.

XNA or the Zune HD **cannot** be used to access the internet like a web browser.

Look at the following thread in the link I provided you, pretty concrete proof from the developers of the XNA platform itself:

[XNA Creators Website](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/20824.aspx)

Comment: and it will *never* be able to do it?

Comment: There is no indication that the XNA APIs will ever offer this.  But you never know what the future holds

Comment: @Valya - See my amended answer for a link to a more detailed explanation

Comment: hm... so I can, for example, create a game for windows with normal networking and connect to it from my Zune?

Comment: The Zune can only network with another Zune so I'm afraid it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

XNA APIs do not allow internet access.  The compact framework implementation does not have the System.Net namespace which of course limits this.  The networking APIs are built in such a way that you can only connect with other XNA based titles.  My guess is that the twitter and other apps are native and provided by microsoft, so they are allowed to use other APIs that aren't available via XNA

Comment: maybe someone have these APIs found and hacked

Comment: The Zune is actually much like the iTouch (or, iPad nano as it were ;-) ). Because it's not really an open device, it's not really prone to hacking.  I mean, there *might* be some homebrew effort somewhere, but I'm not aware of it :-P

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of **OpenZDK**?  OpenZDK allows programs to be run "directly on top of the Zune firmware, with **full access to everything XNA withheld before**".  See below:

> "That’s about to change. Through the work of myself as well as Netrix, Nurta, and the rest of the ZuneBoards Development Front, all Zune models, including the Zune HD, have been hacked. The first true hack available for the Zune, this makes it possible to, for the first time, run applications directly on top of the Zune firmware, with full access to everything XNA withheld before. The limitations of XNA are now no limitations at all."  (from Zune Boards: http://www.zuneboards.com/?p=vB50442)

The OpenZDK wiki: http://zunedevwiki.org/wiki/